Compare same tables from different databases but exclude user_id and date in comparison
I am trying to compare same tables from two different database to achieve the difference rows based on table. For that I have written query:
[select table_name
   from all_tables
  where owner = 'MDWMP']
|
[select @table_name tbl,
        count(*)
   from((select *
        from mdwmp. @table_name:raw 
          minus
          select *
            from mdwmd. @table_name:raw)
         union
         (select *
            from mdwmd. @table_name:raw
          minus
          select *
            from mdwmp. @table_name:raw))] catch(-1403);

where mdwmp is my 1st database and mdwmd is my 2nd database.
This query is giving me an error:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB.

Tables may contain modified_user_id, date&time column. I want to exclude such columns from the comparison and get the unique values.

Presumably at least one of the tables in your schema(s) has a CLOB column, which is being included by the select *, and you can't use set operators (union/minus etc) or anything that requires any sorting with CLOBs. If you want to exclude those, and other columns based on data type or name, you will need to build your dynamic comparison query based on all_tab_columns, not just all_tables.

Can you please help with the dynamic query for it?

Hi, how many tables are there  which you want to compare ? you can use the following query to generate the SQL.    SELECT table_name ,'SELECT ' || LOWER(LISTAGG(column_name,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)) || ' FROM SCHEMA_NAME.' || table_name AS SQL_STMT
FROM ALL_tab_columns WHERE  owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
and data_type <> 'CLOB'
GROUP BY table_name;

Just take out any Clob data type columns out of your selects as these cant be compared against or manipulated. or you can try a dynamic way below:
DECLARE
CURSOR table_cursor IS
    SELECT table_name
    FROM all_tables
    WHERE owner = 'MDWMP';
DECLARE
table_name VARCHAR2(100);
diff_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR table_rec IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'MDWMP') LOOP
    table_name := table_rec.table_name;
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :diff_count FROM (
            SELECT * FROM ' || 'mdwmp.' || table_name || '
            MINUS
            SELECT * FROM ' || 'mdwmd.' || table_name || '
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM ' || 'mdwmd.' || table_name || '
            MINUS
            SELECT * FROM ' || 'mdwmp.' || table_name || '
        )' INTO diff_count;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table: ' || table_name || ', Differences: ' || diff_count);
END LOOP;
END;

